# Detached head branch after SVN-CLONE

Tags: migration, git-svn

In my company, we have moved from svn to git. We did not use any third party tools for this. We ran git svn clone --stdlayout --no-metadata --authors-file=authors.txt  temp_name. This seemed suffucient to get what we wanted. We then pushed the repos to bitbucket. However what we noticed after pushing is, in one of the repos, a branch was missing in bitbucket. So, I did a checkout of the branch, then I got the message 
     "You are in detached HEAD state. You can look around, make experimental
changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this
state without impacting any branches by performing another checkout." Then I googled for resolving the detached head problem but none of the posts talks about the detached head after git svn clone. The main thing I want to achieve is I just want the detached branch pushed to remote master immediately after git svn clone. I do not know what I'm missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't worry much about the detached HEAD message itself. As long as you get the needed revisions in your working copy, simply push it where you want them to be:

```
git push <your_bit_bucket_remote> <revision>:refs/heads/<branch_name_at_bitbucket>
```

where `<revision>` can be something like `HEAD`, `svn/branch_name` or an explicit SHA1.